# #include "fileA.hpp" doesn't work but #include "<full_path>/fileA.hpp" works. Why?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to figure out why does the relative path of the file being included (`fileB.hpp`) not work but the 'absolute' path does?

So in here, `fileA.hpp` includes `fileB.hpp` which resides in a separate directory, and `CMakeLists.txt` of `projectA` does link the library `libB` of `projectB`.

**projectA/include/fileA.hpp**

```
#include "fileB.hpp"  // fatar error: fileB.hpp: No such file or directory
// #include "../../base_2/projectB/include/fileB.hpp" // works
```

**Directories layout**

```
> base
  > projectA
    > include
      > fileA.hpp
    > src
      > fileA.cpp
    > CMakeLists.txt  

> base_2
  > projectB
    > include
      > fileB.hpp
    > src
      > fileB.cpp 
    > CMakeLists.txt
```

**ProjectA CMake**

```
# base/projectA/CMakeLists.txt

set(THIS libA)

add_library(${THIS} SHARED src/fileA.cpp)

target_include_directories(${THIS} PUBLIC include)

target_link_libraries(${THIS} PRIVATE libB)
```

**ProjectB CMake**

```
# base_2/projectB/CMakeLists.txt

add_library(libB STATIC src/fileB.cpp)

target_include_directories(libB PUBLIC include)

target_compile_options(libB PRIVATE -fPIC)
```

Comment: Looks like you did not add the path `../../base_2/projectB/include/` to projectA's include directories so that `#include` would know to look in it when given a relative path. Just because you *link* to `libB` doesn't automatically pull in libB's include directories.

Comment: doesn't linking the library be sufficient? I have other libraries linked in my actual project and I didn't have to include the full path of the headers

Comment: `target_link_libraries()` is supposed to handle the dependency to target properties. You may want to enable verbose makefiles or look at your project file to try to understand the issue.

Comment: Given `CMakeLists.txt`s should work.. if you build them as a **single project** (e.g. you have another `CMakeLists.txt` which includes both `base/projectA/CMakeLists.txt` and `base_2/projectB/CMakeLists.txt`). In that case CMake interpret `libB` in the line `target_link_libraries(${THIS} PRIVATE libB)` as a **target**, which transfers its include directories and options to `libA`. But if you build `base/projectA/CMakeLists.txt` **separately**, then `libB` is just a plain name. It transfers nothing to `libA`.

Answer (score -1):

Because you are using - "" (double quotes) to find the lib/fil that will specifically find the library in the **current working directory** when instead you should use "<" and ">" symbols to make the compiler search for the lib / file in all the directories

So basically
you are doing this - #include"fileb.hpp"
When you should be doing this - #include<fileb.hpp>